# In Eclipse for Java -JDT (DynWeb), Is Eclipse using default ant build.xml ? behind the scenes?

Tags: eclipse, ant, build

I believe when Eclipse installs, ant comes with it.
I should review the default build.xml
( I assume it uses one, whether or not it is obviously included in the project files )
I need to find out where it would store and use this from.

I have some projects / code artifacts that come with a build spec, and may need to use the one specified.  Thanks in advance for your help, and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse doesn't use ant to build your projects, if that's what you are asking. Eclipse builders (such as Java builder) are implemented natively as Eclipse plugins. Eclipse does support integration with Ant... Calling ant targets as part of the build... Calling ant targets as separate tools... Ant is meant to be used to augment IDE-provided facilities when you need something specialized.